# Speeding up pandas apply

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, pandas

I would like to speed up pandas apply function. I have been using swifter . It currently takes about 5 mins for 200000 records using multiprocessing  as below . Is there any way to speed this up further .

```
def partial_match(source_words, dest_words):
    matched_words = ''
    if any(word in dest_words for word in source_words) :
        match_words_list = set(source_words)&set(dest_words) 
        matched_words = ",".join(match_words_list)
    return matched_words

def exact_match(source_words, dest_words):
    matched_words = ''
    if all(word in dest_words for word in source_words) :
        match_words_list = set(source_words)&set(dest_words) 
        matched_words = ",".join(match_words_list)
    return matched_words


series_index = ['match_type', 'matched_words'   ]
def perform_match(x):
    match_series = pd.Series(np.repeat('', len(series_index)), index = series_index)
    if x['remove_bus_ending'] == 'Y':
        x['dest_words'] = x['dest_words_2']
    else:
        x['dest_words'] = x['dest_words_1']
    # exact match
    if (x['partial_match_flag'] == 'Y') :
        match_series['matched_words'] = partial_match(x['source_words'], x['dest_words'])
        if match_series['matched_words'] != '':
            match_series['match_type'] = 'Partial Match'
    elif (x['exact_match_2'] == 'Y'):
        match_series['matched_words'] = exact_match(x['source_words'], x['dest_words'])
        if match_series['matched_words'] != '':
            match_series['match_type'] = 'Exact Match' 

    return match_series

from multiprocessing import  Pool
from functools import partial
import numpy as np

def parallelize(data, func, num_of_processes=8):
    data_split = np.array_split(data, num_of_processes)
    pool = Pool(num_of_processes)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

def run_on_subset(func, data_subset):
    return data_subset.swifter.apply(func, axis=1)

def parallelize_on_rows(data, func, num_of_processes=8):
    return parallelize(data, partial(run_on_subset, func), num_of_processes)

df[match_series]  = parallelize_on_rows(df, perform_match)
```

below is some sample data

```
flag1   partial_match_flag  exact_match_flag    source_words    dest_word_2 dest_words_1
0   N   Y   N   [song, la]  [urban, karamay, credit, city, co, kunlun, com...   [ltd, urban, karamay, credit, city, co, kunlun...
1   N   Y   N   [song, la]  [al, abdulah, nasser]   [al, abdulah, nasser]
2   N   Y   N   [song, la]  [al, abdulah, nasser]   [al, abdulah, nasser]
3   N   Y   N   [song, la]  [abdulamir, mahdi]  [abdulamir, mahdi]
4   N   Y   N   [song, la]  [abdullah, al, nasser]  [abdullah, al, nasser]
5   N   Y   N   [song, la]  [abu, al, jud]  [abu, al, jud]
6   N   Y   N   [song, la]  [al, herz, adam]    [al, herz, adam]
```

Comment: "[However if you have CPU bound applications; one of the most important things you can known, is that if you add threading to a CPU bound application will it go faster or slower? Slower.](https://youtu.be/Bv25Dwe84g0?t=412)"

Comment: Please edit your question so that you explain what your code does. Currently it is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## flag as boolean

If you change the flags from `'Y'` and `'N'` to `True` and `False` You can use boolean indexing. This should speed up a lot of things already

## set

You check for each combination `word in dest_words for word in source_words` on a `list` of words. If the check matches, you convert to a `set`. The containment check would be sped up by checking against a list, but using `set` comparisons would speed this up a lot.

```
import typing

def partial_match(
    source_words: typing.Set[str], dest_words: typing.Set[str], index=None
) -> typing.Tuple[typing.Any, typing.Optional[str]]:
    intersection = source_words & dest_words
    if intersection:
        return index, ", ".join(intersection)
    return index, None

def exact_match(
    source_words: typing.Set[str], dest_words: typing.Set[str], index=None
) -> typing.Tuple[typing.Any, typing.Optional[str]]:
    if source_words == dest_words:
        return index, ", ".join(source_words)
    return index, None
```

The reason I chose to return the index along with it is to be able to reconstruct the series easier when reassembling everything.

## Don't touch the original data

You change your source data inplace (by adding columns). Better would be to leave this untouched, and keep the destination words etc in separate series.

## [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)

You can replace calls like this

```
if x['remove_bus_ending'] == 'Y':
        x['dest_words'] = x['dest_words_2']
    else:
        x['dest_words'] = x['dest_words_1']
```

with `Series.where`

```
a = pd.Series(list("abcd"))
b = pd.Series(list("efgh"))
c = pd.Series([True, True, False, True])
b.where(c, other=a)
```

> ```
> 0    e
> 1    f
> 2    c
> 3    h
> dtype: object
> ```

If your data looks like this:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

def setify(s):
    return s.str.strip("[]").str.split(", ").apply(set)

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), sep="\s\s+", index_col=False, engine='python')
df["source_words"] = setify(df["source_words"])
df["dest_words_1"] = setify(df["dest_words_1"])
df["dest_word_2"] = setify(df["dest_word_2"])
df["remove_bus_ending"] = df["remove_bus_ending"] == "Y"
df["partial_match_flag"] = df["partial_match_flag"] == "Y"
df["exact_match_flag"] = df["exact_match_flag"] == "Y"
```

## intermediate dataframe

If you want to split the dataframe with arraysplit, you'll need to provide an intermediate form with the info you need:

```
df_intermediate = pd.concat(
    [
        df["dest_word_2"]
        .where(df["remove_bus_ending"], other=df["dest_words_1"])
        .rename("dest_words"),
        df["source_words"],
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

You can even split it immediately according to what matching is needed

```
df_intermediate_partial = df_intermediate.loc[df["partial_match_flag"]]
df_intermediate_exact = df_intermediate.loc[df["exact_match_flag"]]
```

## applying the function

not parallel:

```
result_partial = list(
    map(
        partial_match,
        df_intermediate_partial["source_words"],
        df_intermediate_partial["dest_words"],
        df_intermediate_partial.index,
    )
)


results_exact = list(
    map(
        exact_match,
        df_intermediate_exact["source_words"],
        df_intermediate_exact["dest_words"],
        df_intermediate_exact.index,
    )
)

result = pd.Series(result_partial + results_exact)
```

This should be easy to parallelize. Since I'm no expert on that, I'll leave that to others.

## context manager

Most of the examples I found in the `multiprocessing` documantation work with a context manager that takes care of the closing of the pool

```
with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    ... # parallel part of the code
```

Comment: flagging as boolean and setifying data has improved speed drastically